# Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Calculate $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/(2x),R/(4))$

Tags: homological-algebra

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Calculate $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/(2x),R/(4))$ as an
>   $R$-module.

My guess is that it's somehow isomorphic to $R/(2)$, as $2$ seems to be the greatest common divisor of $2x$ and $4$, however this is just a guess.

In general, is there a way to calculate $\operatorname{Hom}_{S[x]}(S[x]/I,S[x]/J)$, for some ring $S$ and ideals $I,J\subset S[x]$?

Comment: Is it $Hom_R$  or $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: The excersise I was given says $Hom_R$. Just out of curiosity, does anything in general hold if it was $Hom_\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I asked this because of your second question.

Comment: Ahh okay, that was a typo from me

Comment: There is exactly one morphism of $R$-algebras from $R$ to $R/I$, for any commutative ring $R$ and any ideal $I$....

Comment: I think the question may be asking about $R$-linear maps, not just $R$-algebra maps.

Comment: Are we familiar with terms like "projective'' and "short exact sequence''?

Comment: Yes a little - definitions and such